# How to add directory in CVS

Tags: cvs

I have a CVS Server. I want to add a new directory in some already existing directory. How can I do this?

CVS `add` command adds files in already existing directory. I want to know how to add a sub folder in a CVS folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the directory in a local workspace. `cvs add <dirname>`. That's it.

Note that unlike adding files, which require a subsequent `cvs commit`, when adding a directory the add happens on the server as soon as you've done the `cvs add` so make sure you choose the right directory name.

Comment: for this, i need to check out whole root directory. I don't want to do that. Can you suggest a method to add a directory without checking out whole directory.

Comment: You probably only need to check out the parent of the directory you want to add new new directory too. If you want to add a new directory to the root, do a `cvs co -l <module>`. (`-l` --ell not the number one-- is don't recurse into subdirs) If you want to add a new directory to `foo/bar`, do `cvs co -l <module>/foo/bar`. Then add the directory as described above.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
mkdir <dirname>
cvs add <dirname>
```

Answer (score 0):

How To Add Directories And Subdirectories To A CVS Repository

Here is a quick way to add directories and subdirectories to an existing CVS repository:

```
cvs add top_level_directory
find top_level_directory -type d -print | xargs cvs add
find top_level_directory -name CVS -prune -o -type f -print | xargs cvs add
```

The instruction below adds the top-level called top_level_directory directory to the CVS repository:

```
cvs add top_level_directory
```

The instruction below finds all subdirectories under `top_level_directory` and issues a cvs add command to subdirectories that are found:

```
find <folder_name> -type d -print | xargs cvs add
```

The instruction below finds all files not including CVS files and issues a cvs add command:

```
find <folder_name> -name CVS -prune -o -type f -print | xargs cvs add
```

Thanks to https://paritycheck.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/how-to-add-directories-and-subdirectories-to-a-cvs-repository/